# SAMS Teach Yourself dismissModalViewController Not Working

Tags: iphone, email

I'm just learning iPhone application development and found a problem with one of the examples from the "SAMS Teach Yourself iPhone Application Development in 24hrs". The source can be downloaded from http://www.iapps4you.com/iphone/photograbber.zip

Once saved do a build and run in the SDK and then select the little "information" symbol which displaye the information screen. Selecting "Feedback" will display the mail composer and does allow the user to complete all the required fields.. The Problem comes when you try to "Send" or "Cancel", it appears control never gets passed back to the "mailComposeController"

I'd appreciate anyone having a look at this code and leeting me know if you can get the app to close the mail window when the "Send" or "Cancel" is selected..

Answer (score 1):

In `-(IBAction)sendFeedback:(id)sender` of FlipsideViewController.m change

```
mailer.delegate = self;
```

to

```
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

Also, to fix the compile warnings in FlipsideViewController.h change

```
-(IBAction)sendFeedback;
```

to

```
-(IBAction)sendFeedback:(id)sender;
```

Comment: Thanks That resolved the problem. I'd also picked the second issue up as well.. Thanks